# Call to a member function on null?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have done all sorts of things to understand what is actually wrong with the code, but I just couldn't figure out what was causing this error.

Below is class called `Topic` :

```
class Topic {

        // Init DB variables
        private $db;

        /*
        *   Constructor
        */
        public function __contruct() {
            $this->db = new Database();

        }

        /*
        *   Get All Topics
        */
        public function getAllTopics() {

            $this->db->query("SELECT topics.*, users.username, 
                              users.avatar, categories.name 
                              FROM topics 
                              INNER JOIN users 
                              ON topics.user_id = users.id 
                              INNER JOIN categories 
                              ON topics.category_id = categories.id 
                              ORDER BY create_date DESC");


            // Assign the results
            $results = $this->db->resultset();

            return $results;
        }
    }
```

When I create an object of class `Topic`,

```
$topic = new Topic();
$results = $topic->getAllTopics();
```

there is always an error like this :

> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function query() on null in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/forumproject/libraries/Topic.php
>   on line 25 i.e. $this->db->query(...)

The `Database` class is working perfectly as I have run tests independently for that class, and there is no problem with it.

Here is the Database class :

```
<?php 

    /*
    * Using PDO for the first time in my life.
    */

    class Database  {

        private $host = DB_HOST;
        private $user = DB_USER;
        private $pass = DB_PASS;
        private $dbname = DB_NAME;

        private $dbh;
        private $error;
        private $stmt;

        public function __construct()   {
            // Set DSN
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

            // Set options
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );

            // Create a new PDO instance
            try { 
                $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
            }
            // Catch the errors using exceptions handler
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function query($query){
            $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        }

        public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
            if(isnull($type)){
                switch(true){
                    case is_int($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        break;

                    case is_bool($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;

                    case is_null($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;

                    default : 
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }

            $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
        }


        public function execute(){
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        }

        public function resultset(){
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }

        public function single(){
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }

        public function rowCount(){
            return $this->stmt->rowCount();
        }

        public function lastInsertId(){
            return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        }

        public function beginTransaction(){
            return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
        }

        public function endTransaction(){
            return $this->bbh->commit();
        }

        public function cancelTransaction(){
            return $this->dbh->rollBack();
        }


    }

?>
```

Comment: Is the `Database` class in the same file? If not you have to `include`/`require` it.

Comment: Is this your complete Topic file? Fatal error suggest on line no 25, where are query function is called on line no 19

Comment: @TomUdding yes I included it.

Comment: Yes. I have used var_dump($this->db), and it returns NULL, even when I have included the database file using includes.

Comment: Can you also add the `Database` file?

Comment: @TomUdding just did. Have a look

Comment: Why are you writing a new class instead of just extending PDO? Also there is rarely a need to bind parameters using PDO. Just pass them as values to `execute()`. Nowhere are you checking that the database object was created successfully. This is probably the problem.

Comment: @manjula can you check what is in `$this->dbh` (`Database` class)?

Comment: @miken32 because he is using [this old code](https://github.com/kkirsche/PDO-Database-Class/blob/master/class_database.php) from kkirsche.

Comment: @TomUdding when i run var_dump on `$this->dbh`, it returns `NULL`.

Comment: @TomUdding I ran this : `var_dump($topic->db->dbh)` then it returned `NULL`

Comment: @TomUdding, and gmc pointed out in his question, I have a typo in Topic class at __construct. My bad. Thanks for the assistance anyways.

Comment: Just noticed it, I should look better in the future.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have a typo in `public function __contruct()`, it should be `public function __construct() {` (you are missing an s)

Comment: I have no words to describe how I feel right now. I am really ashamed, and on the other hand I am really thankful to you. I have been stuck with this since past 3 hours.

Comment: Do not worry, it happens a lot ;)

Comment: When the answer is: "you misspelled something", then the appropriate way to resolve the question is to close it as **Off-topic Typo**.

Comment: @StillLearning now you can be ashamed even more, as more than **hundred thousand** people went here for help, only to learn that you made some typo many years ago.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when trying to access methods on objects that are not instantiated. Always check if an object is instantiated before trying to use it.

Comment: From the practical point of view, this generalized suggestion makes no sense. One cannot literally "check if an object is instantiated before trying to use it". It will litter one's code with thousands if useless conditions. Also, such a condition may suppress a helpful error which would have helped a programmer to fix the problem. Like, in the OP. With your suggestion this code will simply do nothing and say nothing